# how to Move items from a folder by the same number of folders to others folder by bash shell?

Tags: file, copy

if there are many folders in "master" folder with no ragular pattern.
how to divide  by "n" and  deliver  to  several folders ?

if 50folders in "master" folders , and other location  are ten "master1" ~ "master10" folders so ,  need to be delivered 5folders in master 
from "master1" to "master10"

so finally   each from master1 to master10  will be contained five folders .

Comment: What is used OS? What is your tool?

Comment: i am using mac os 10.12.x version , but bash shell version same with latest macos .